# Aggregate Function in MongoDB, Parse.com

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, aggregation-framework

For a document below:

```
{
  profile: String
  [{
    year: Integer,
    quarter: Integer,
    rate: Integer
  }]
}
```

How to get average of rating every quarter?:

```
2014    1   3.5
2014    2   4.0
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your profile as an array.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {"$unwind" : "$profile"},
  {"$group": { "_id" : { "year": "$profile.year", "quarter": "$profile.quarter"}, average: { $avg: "$profile.rate" }}} 
])
```

More info :

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/